# find all the child tables for a table in sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I need to archive data from a table but same should be done for all the child tables also. So how to find all the child tables of a table in sybase ASE 15. 
example: I have employee table which have child address. The address table has again a child phone. Here how can i find the table names address and phone when I search for table employee.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at Jailer: it claims it can do that automatically: http://jailer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The easy way that I can recommend you is migrating the DDL to mysql with the proper changes, after that mysql workbench can recreate through reverse engineering a diagram of all the relationships in your database .